# Обясните что делает код?

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите, что делает данный [код](https://github.com/amadvance/advancecomp/blob/master/compress.cc#L238):

```
sz_passes = level.iter > 15 ? level.iter : 15;
if (sz_passes > 255)
  sz_passes = 255;
sz_fastbytes = 255;
```

Хочу сразу оговориться, я не программист.

Comment: раз Вы не программист, тогда уточните, какой ответ Вы хотите получить, так как ответ "выставляет значение переменных в зависимости от значения других" Вам видимо ничего не даст.

Comment: @lorents Я - тоже не программист. Я - ответчик. Отвечаю здесь на вопросы.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В этом преддложении

```
sz_passes = level.iter > 15 ? level.iter : 15;
```

переменной `sz_passes` присваивается максимальное значение из двух значений: того, что содержится в переменной  `level.iter`, и 15.

То есть минимальное значение `sz_passes` в любом случае не может быть меньше 15.

В этом предложение

```
if (sz_passes > 255)
  sz_passes = 255;
```

переменная `sz_passes` ограничивается сверху значением 255.

То есть если оказалось, что после предыдущего предложение текущее значение `sz_passes` больше 255, то установить его равным 255.

А в этом предложении

```
sz_fastbytes = 255;
```

переменной `sz_fastbytes` присваивается значение 255.

Хочу сразу также отметить, что это - плохой код, так как использует никому непонятные "магические" числа 15 и 255, которые не способствуют пониманию кода. Лучше было бы, если этим числам были присвоены некоторые осмысленные имена.

Answer (score 3):

Первая строка - это [тернарный оператор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), результат которого будет записан в переменную `sz_passes`. Суть его такая: если `level.iter` больше `15`, то в переменную `sz_passes` запишется значение `level.iter`, если же меньше `15` или равно `15`, то в переменную `sz_passes` запишется значение `15`.

Дальше идет вторая строка

```
 if (sz_passes > 255)
```

Она означает такое: если переменная `sz_passes` больше `255`, то переменной `sz_passes` будет присвоено `255` в третьей строке.

```
sz_passes = 255;
```

В четвертой строке переменной `sz_fastbytes` будет присвоено `255`.

```
sz_fastbytes = 255;
```

Comment: Чего-чего??? `sz_fastbytes` присваивается `255` **всегда**!

Comment: Да, правильно, я ошибся.